# A C# Socket that gets an IP address automatically

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

I've started socket programming with C#. Previously, I had some experience working with sockets under Java; and everything is fine with C# too except that:

C# sockets don't acquire IP address automatically. In Java, server sockets only need a port, and then when they are constructed, the automatically acquire a usable IP that can be returned by a method (I don't remember the name of that method).

in C#, a server socket must be given an IP, or otherwise it can't be constructed. I want the socket to find an IP automatically, but I tried `IPAddress.any`, and it only returns `0.0.0.0` which is just weird (I don't even know what that means! Listening on every IP?)
IP address of the server socket can be returned by `localEndPoint` property, so I just want the socket to grab an IP and then I'll figure what it is using that method.

How is this possible ?

Comment: I could very easily be wrong, but I think 0.0.0.0 is a special case which says use any IP address. I believe this happens when socket programming in C++ as well.

Comment: @KshitijMehta You are exactly right. That's what it means - every available ip.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that still doesn't answer the question. I don't want my program to use any IP, because, say, I want to connect a socket to this server from a remote client. What address should I give this socket? 0.0.0.0??

Comment: Listening on 0.0.0.0 means *all IP addresses* so yes - that *would* work for accepting remote connections.

Comment: But how is that possible? All IP addresses? I'm talking about connection over the web! If this socket is listening on ALL the IP addresses then it should accept ANY socket that is requesting for a connection from ANY place!

Comment: I just tried giving the client 0.0.0.0 as the ip address and it didn't work! Error: "IP address isn't valid in its context". Can somebody provide me a solution for this? How can I figure out the IP address of the server?

Comment: The only IP that works is 127.0.0.1, and that's because I launched both applications on localhost. Also, the IP address of the PC itself works, too, but again, it won't work if I try to connect from a remote PC that's not connected to the same gateway.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments. the 0.0.0.0 means "any ip address", which is exactly what you indicated in your constructor.

If you want it to only listen on a specific IP, you need to explicitly denote that IP in the constructor. It won't pick one at random, and you shouldn't want it to.

Incidentally, there is a different class for listing the IPs available on a system. Let me know in a comment if that's what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how am I supposed to know which IP is usable? I tried this, but each time it says "The requested address is not valid in its context", and that's why I want it to find an available IP automatically. How can solve this?

Comment: Simple. All IP means all IP that ARE ON ANY NETWORK CARD ON THE SERVER. Sockets do not "get" Ip addresses, network cards do. A socket can ever only use an IP address that is available on the server network cards. it will NEVER go out and grab one. All IP means "all that are on the server" and knowing those if the job of the admin setting things up.

Comment: OK. Here's the deal: I have a client program somewhere in Texas, and I have a server program in new york. The client is supposed to connect to the server, but it doesn't know the IP. Server is listening to 0.0.0.0. My friend in New York tells me anything I need about the server. What IP should I give the client?

Comment: He tells me anything except the IP address! He probably CAN find it, but he doesn't know how. I mean, if you were him, how would you find that specific IP address? Is it the one that is used by Internet connection, and shown on http://www.whatismyip.com/?

Comment: @V0R73X *He doesn't know how*??? Wow... Most likely it would be the one shown by that website, yes. More likely than what is shown by the internet connection on the computer itself (because that's more likely to be a private address that isn't accessible from the Internet).

Comment: Yes thank you I guess I'm reaching to an answer! (we are not some professional programmers we're just teenagers!) OK thanks for your last reply, but I tried to connect to the server program many times and well, it just doesn't connect. I mean, he starts the server there, goes to that website, tells me his IP, and I telnet to that IP, but I can't connect. I guess it's not accessible from the internet? If so, how can I make it accessible?

Comment: @Vor73x That would be more of a networking question. A firewall/router is likely blocking.